# YAP PROLOG timeout issue

Tags: prolog, yap

Can anyone explain why the following YAP code does not result in the variable `Result` being unified with `time_out`?

```
?- time_out(sleep(3),1,Result).
Result = success.
?- time_out(sleep(3),2,Result).
Result = success.
 ?- time_out(sleep(3),1000,Result).
Result = success.
 ?- time_out(sleep(3),2000,Result).
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/documentation.html#Timeout), the predicate should work as follows:

> `time_out(+Goal, +Timeout, -Result)`
>
> Execute goal `Goal` with time limited
>   `Timeout`, where `Timeout` is measured in milliseconds. If the goal
>   succeeds, unify `Result` with `success`. If the timer expires before the
>   goal terminates, unify `Result` with `time_out`.

Comment: Which version? Compiled with or without threads support?

Comment: YAP 6.3.3 without thread support

Answer (score 3):

YAP's documentation also states that:

> Last, even though the timer is set in milliseconds, the current
>   implementation relies on `alarm/3`, and therefore can only offer
>   precision on the scale of seconds.

In turn, the documentation for `sleep/1` states:

> Block the current thread for `Time` seconds.

But the problem in this case is likely not related to the times but for the call to `sleep/1` blocking the current thread where the `time_out/3` call is being itself executed. Nevertheless, I tried the `time_out/3` predicate with other goals and also couldn't not get the expected time out. Thus, there might be some bug in it.

Comment: I made the YAP developer aware of this thread. I suggest you contact him directly or make a post to the YAP mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>(Somehow I missed this thread)</sup>

First, `sleep/1` and `time_out/3` do not flock together.  `time_out/3` waits for a certain amount of milliseconds of CPU-time or thread-time, whereas `sleep/1` sleeps real-time seconds.  There are certain limitations in YAP compared to the [original in SICStus](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dtimeout.html#index-time_005fout_002f3-_0028timeout_0029-1), see the manual for more.

In the current development version from the git (last commit d5ce9a137668fe1ae34e2d47c91fc2725ae04a5f,
Date:   Wed Apr 22 14:21:20 2015 -0600), the mechanism seems to be broken.

In an older version of 6.3.4 I get:

```
YAP 6.3.4 (x86_64-linux): Tue Jan 29 12:39:29 CET 2013
MYDDAS version MYDDAS-0.9.1
 ?- use_module(library(timeout)).
 % reconsulting /opt/gupu/share/Yap/timeout.yap...
  % reconsulting /opt/gupu/share/Yap/hacks.yap...
  % reconsulted /opt/gupu/share/Yap/hacks.yap in module yap_hacks, 0 msec 15472 bytes
 % reconsulted /opt/gupu/share/Yap/timeout.yap in module timeout, 0 msec 48240 bytes
true.
 ?- 100000000=J,time(time_out((between(1,J,N),N=J),1,R)).
% 0.008 CPU in 0.007 seconds (114% CPU)
J = 100000000,
R = time_out.
 ?- 100000000=J,time(time_out((between(1,J,N),N=J),10000,R)).
% 9.985 CPU in 10.003 seconds ( 99% CPU)
J = 100000000,
R = time_out.
 ?- 100000000=J,time(time_out((between(1,J,N),N=J),100000,R)).
% 23.477 CPU in 23.522 seconds ( 99% CPU)
J = N = 100000000,
R = success.
 ?- 100000000=J,time(time_out(sleep(10),1,R)).
% 0.000 CPU in 10.000 seconds (Inf% CPU)
J = 100000000,
R = success.
```